# Variable is not updated in SSIS For Each Loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create simple project in which I'd like to download XML files from given website. I have stored files names in DataBase table. What I have done looking at this tutorial: [Implementing Foreach Looping Logic in SSIS](http://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/) is:

a. Read all distinct rows from my Table (let's call it XMLTable)
b. Assign result of this query to User variable called: nameOfFileToDownload
c. Created For Each Loop container
d. Configured to assign localy each row with file name to download to: nameFileForeachLoop variable
e. Download files from concate link as a path using HTTPManager with dynamic file name from nameFileForeachLoop variable.
f. Created XMLFlatFile connection for dummy file - I assumed after reading from above tutorial.

The problem is now that this loop container works but doesn't download files separately - still to one file which at the end is empty. My `nameFileForeachLoop` variable is not updated during each LOOP iteration. What's more I have noticed that during FLAT FILE creation I have only CSV and TXT extension available. I have tried many approaches but without results. Can you help me how to download XML files?
For example I have following link to XML: nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c001z180102.xml What changes here is last part of this link with XML extension which I get from my XMLTable.

I have configured my components as follows:

[image: photo1]
[image: photo2]
[image: photo3]
[image: photo4]
[image: photo5]
[image: photo6]
[image: photo7]
[image: photo8]
[image: photo9]

Comment: How do you know it's not updating the variable? If you add a Script Task inside the Foreach Loop Container that simply prints the variable, similar to what I have [here](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html) does the execution results show all the expected values?

Comment: I have created simple script according to your answer and now it is showing me values for that variable. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but need some amendements.

1. Do not create and configure **Flat File Destination** connection manager unless you are creating tables in **.CSV** or **.TXT** files. In provided example author selects data with dynamic queries and stores the results in dynamic txt files. As I understand, this is not your case.
2. Here are some examples how to download and save files with HTTP in SSIS. [Sample download script](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx) and [Review of different approaches to HTTP download](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ru/2011/05/download-source-file-from-website-with.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response on my topic. I have used your examples and now created dynamic script in which I download files according to it's name. Now it is working.